# Need to check if a value is within the range (upper limit and lower limit) configured in drools decision table

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools. Now I need to validate one value is within the range configured in drools decision table.

Scenario: Salary is the condition and grade is the action (output).

I need to configure the salary like this
(0 - 10000) -   Grade A,
(10000 - 15000)  - Grade B

Please help me to design the drools decision table.
Can I use "in"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `<` and `>` (or `<=` and `>=`) just like you'd do a normal comparison in Java or DRL.

Pseudo-code, it would look something like this:

```
| CONDITION        | CONDITION       | ACTION  |
| salary >= $param | salary < $param | $result |
| MIN              | MAX             | GRADE   |
| 0                | 10000           | A       |
| 10000            | 15000           | B       |
```

`in` is a valid keyword in Drools, but it's not for this. It's for identifying if a value is in a given list. For example, if you wanted to check that some value $color is one of red, blue, or green, you'd do like: `$color in ("red", "blue", "green")`. It's not appropriate for figuring out if a number is in a range.